# Flutter app not running with iOS platform

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cross-platform

Created Flutter app with Linux platform, Running iOS source in the Mac system

Steps followed to create app with  Linux platform

1. download flutter library from below [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux)
2. set flutter sdk path as per describe in above site.
3. run command: flutter doctor
4. run command: flutter create flutter_demo
5. run command: flutter run
6. successfully app install in android device.
7. create .zip file of my flutter project and pass to Mac System setup.

Steps followed to run in iOS app:

1. Flutter install in following path :-
   Users⁩/apple⁩/⁨Documents⁩/⁨Flutter⁩/⁨setup⁩/flutter
2. Using examples of flutter sdk we have tested flutter properly install or not and all apps run successfully.
3. Now we have tried to run project that make in our android system but give me errors like this:

Getting following errors:
1)
Warning! This package referenced a Flutter repository via the .packages file
that is no longer available. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is
currently executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: /Users/apple/Documents/Flutter/setup/flutter
  previous reference  :
  /backup/mayur/Flutter_development/flutter_linux_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter
This can happen if you deleted or moved your copy of the Flutter repository, or
if it was on a volume that is no longer mounted or has been mounted at a
different location. Please check your system path to verify that you are running
the expected version (run 'flutter --version' to see which flutter is on your
path).

2)
lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Error when reading
'file:///backup/mayur/Flutter_development/flutter_linux_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/material.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

So any one have solution for that then please suggest. It can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install flutter packages.
**flutter pub get** or  **flutter packages get**